# How to times all the values together in an array list

Tags: java, arrays, list, math

I would like to multiply each value inside an arraylist of integers. For example,

I have an array list which contains the following numbers:

```
5, 5, 5, 5
```

How would I create an integer that contains all these numbers multiplied by eachother:

```
int x = 5 * 5 * 5 * 5
```

In my case I'm returning it with a method, like so:

```
List<Integer> stack = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public int multiply() {
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < stack.size(); i++) {
        x *= stack.get(i);
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Where's your code? what have you tried?

Comment: The simplicity of the solution denotes a lack of effort.  This basic idea is to simply iterate the list and multiple the values together...Can you describe the issues you are having?

Comment: 0 times anything is 0. Don't rush it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Integer> stack = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public int multiply() {
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < stack.size(); i++) {
        x *= stack.get(i);
    }
    return x;
}
```

Think about, what ONE time `0*` means to the final number..? Got it? Fix it!

Answer (score 3):

Simply loop through your `ArrayList` and multiply away:

```
int foo=1;
for(int i : list) {
   foo *= i;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a problem here

```
public int multiply() {
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < stack.size(); i++) {
        x *= stack.get(i);
    }
     return x;
}
```

since you initialise x with zero - multiply it by anything and its still zero.
Change this line to

```
 int x = 1;
```

and you should be good

Answer (score 1):

Umm   you should initialize your result (`x`) to 1!   (zero times anything is zero)

Answer (score 0):

```
int number1 = 1;
   for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
   number1 *= list.get(i);
   }
System.out.println(number1);
```

I made 'number1' equal 1 because any number times 1 is the number. after the loop 'number1' is printed. Complete syntax of 'number1 *= list.get(i);' -> 
number1 = number1 * list.get(i);